# How to remove index column after Converting xlsx to csv using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd

data_xls=pd.read_excel('/users/adam/abc.xlsx',index=False) 
data_xls.to_csv('def.csv,encoding='utf-8')
```

Also tried:

```
data_xls=pd.read_excel('/users/adam/abc.xlsx',index_col=False)
data_xls=pd.read_excel('/users/adam/abc.xlsx',index=None)
data_xls=pd.read_excel('/users/adam/abc.xlsx',index_col=None)
```

Actual Output:

```
     Name    Age

0    Adam    24

1    Steve   25

2    Jhon    23
```

Expected Output:

```
Name    Age

Adam    24

Steve   25

Jhon    23
```

Is there a way If I can drop the index column before inserting the data into a hive table?

Comment: Use Code Segments for code. It is really difficult to the accustomed eye to read non-monospaced code.

Comment: Use `Dataframe.drop()` method to drop any row or column. Check more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Comment: @pault I am doing this within pyspark and this file is going to be used to load the data to a Hive table.

Comment: @saketk21, I went ahead and ignored the index while converting my file from xlsx to csv.                                                                                                                    data_xls.to_csv('def.csv,encoding='utf-8',index=False)

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when writing file you can use the following code if you don't want pandas to write the index column in the csv file

```
pd.to_csv('your.csv', index=False)
```

Also if you want to drop the index when reading a file you should be able to do it through:

```
df = pd.read_csv('some.csv').drop(['Unnamed 0'],axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks much inder, I got rid of the index while converting the file to csv.